# Heroku deployment issue with Rails + React, incorrect peer dependency issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails+React app initially started with the codebase here: https://github.com/timscott/react-devise-sample

When I try to deploy the app to Heroku, the app is failing with the following log output below. What am I doing wrong and where can I start investigating to fix?

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 3143, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2841/2841), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3143/3143), 1.29 MiB | 1.05 MiB/s, done.
Total 3143 (delta 1966), reused 107 (delta 6)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  6.3.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 6.3.1...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.3.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.10.3
remote:        Resolving yarn version 0.28.4...
remote:        Downloading and installing yarn (0.28.4)...
remote:        Installed yarn 0.28.4
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (not-found)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
remote:        yarn install v0.28.4
remote:        warning package.json: No license field
remote:        warning react_devise_sample: No license field
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        warning "fetch-bluebird@1.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "bluebird@^2".
remote:        warning "fetch-bluebird@1.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "fetch-polyfill@*".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        $ yarn run build && yarn run deploy && echo 'Client built!'
remote:        yarn run v0.28.4
remote:        warning package.json: No license field
remote:        $ cd client && yarn && yarn run build && cd ..
remote:        warning ../package.json: No license field
remote:        warning fsevents@1.0.17: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        warning "inline-style-prefixer@3.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "caniuse-api@^1.5.2".
remote:        warning "fetch-bluebird@1.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "bluebird@^2".
remote:        warning "fetch-bluebird@1.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "fetch-polyfill@*".
remote:        warning "react-redux@5.0.4" has incorrect peer dependency "redux@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "redux-form@6.7.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-redux@^4.3.0 || ^5.0.0".
remote:        warning "redux-form@6.7.0" has incorrect peer dependency "redux@^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "react-icon-base@2.0.7" has incorrect peer dependency "prop-types@*".
remote:        warning "babel-loader@6.2.10" has incorrect peer dependency "babel-core@^6.0.0".
remote:        warning "babel-loader@6.2.10" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc".
remote:        warning "eslint-config-react-app@0.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "babel-eslint@^7.0.0".
remote:        warning "eslint-config-react-app@0.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^3.16.1".
remote:        warning "eslint-config-react-app@0.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint-plugin-flowtype@^2.21.0".
remote:        warning "eslint-config-react-app@0.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint-plugin-import@^2.0.1".
remote:        warning "eslint-config-react-app@0.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
remote:        warning "eslint-config-react-app@0.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react@^6.4.1".
remote:        warning "eslint-loader@1.6.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@>=1.6.0 <4.0.0".
remote:        warning "eslint-plugin-flowtype@2.21.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@>=2.0.0".
remote:        warning "eslint-plugin-import@2.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@2.x - 3.x".
remote:        warning "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@4.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^2.10.2 || 3.x".
remote:        warning "eslint-plugin-react@6.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^1.9.11".
remote:        warning "html-webpack-plugin@2.24.0" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta".
remote:        warning "url-loader@0.5.7" has incorrect peer dependency "file-loader@*".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server@1.16.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@>=1.3.0 <3".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-middleware@1.10.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc.0".
remote:        warning "ajv-keywords@1.5.1" has incorrect peer dependency "ajv@>=4.10.0".
remote:        warning "marked-terminal@1.7.0" has incorrect peer dependency "marked@^0.3.3".
remote:        warning "react-toggle@4.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "prop-types@^15.3.0".
remote:        warning "reactstrap@4.8.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-transition-group@^1.1.2".
remote:        warning "redux-form-material-ui@4.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "redux-form@6".
remote:        warning ../package.json: No license field
remote:        
remote:        > client@0.1.0 build-css /tmp/build_e11b9001c5621f36cdc8eb26f091082d/client
remote:        > node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/
remote:        
remote:        sh: 1: node-sass-chokidar: not found
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-128-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_e11b9001c5621f36cdc8eb26f091082d/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_e11b9001c5621f36cdc8eb26f091082d/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "run" "build-css"
remote:        npm ERR! node v6.3.1
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
remote:        npm ERR! file sh
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR! syscall spawn
remote:        npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build-css: `node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/`
remote:        npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build-css script 'node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/'.
remote:        npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
remote:        npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the client package,
remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote:        npm ERR!     node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/
remote:        npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm bugs client
remote:        npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm owner ls client
remote:        npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_e11b9001c5621f36cdc8eb26f091082d/client/npm-debug.log
remote:        error Command failed with exit code 1.
remote:        error Command failed with exit code 1.
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
remote:        error Command failed with exit code 1.
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - This project was built with yarn, which is new and under development. Some projects can still be built more reliably with npm
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#build-behavior
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to xxx-copland.
remote:
```